# Hotmail blocks my SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, outlook, email-bounces

Recently i discovered that hotmail has blocked my SMTP once again.

The error code is `Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 SC-001 (COL004-MC5F28)`

I only send for my web based online 2d text game : http://www.monstermmorpg.com

- Activation emails
- Password recovery emails

It is free to play so you can register to test email attributes. Once you register it will send you verification email

I have contacted Microsoft team and they have swiftly removed the block thankfully. But i want to prevent further blockages

Here an email source code send from my SMTP server to my own hotmail account

So are there anything wrong with my server configuration? anything missing? what do you suggest? thank you

```
Received: from DB4PR08MB0208.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com (10.161.250.26) by
 AM3PR08MB0200.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com (10.161.35.151) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.539.14 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 11 Jul 2016 17:00:33
 +0000
Received: from AM3PR08CA0042.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com (10.160.207.180) by
 DB4PR08MB0208.eurprd08.prod.outlook.com (10.161.250.26) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.528.16; Mon, 11 Jul 2016 17:00:32 +0000
Received: from HE1EUR01FT049.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
 (2a01:111:f400:7e1f::209) by AM3PR08CA0042.outlook.office365.com
 (2a01:111:e400:8840::52) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id 15.1.539.14 via
 Frontend Transport; Mon, 11 Jul 2016 17:00:32 +0000
Received: from BAY004-MC5F20.hotmail.com (10.152.0.56) by
 HE1EUR01FT049.mail.protection.outlook.com (10.152.0.221) with Microsoft SMTP
 Server (TLS) id 15.1.534.7 via Frontend Transport; Mon, 11 Jul 2016 17:00:31
 +0000
Received: from MonsterMMORPG.com ([138.128.2.226]) by BAY004-MC5F20.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
     Mon, 11 Jul 2016 10:00:27 -0700
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
  s=s1024; d=monstermmorpg.com;
  h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject:content-type:message-id;
  bh=VWCrPK7DB0WuVjry+X0TdhElRdFfzJr4P6679X2gvN4=;
  b=dcE1DN+cs4hebPthdZoijyVCLJmVTMyk4Un9nUIrkbOGnMq0vaSAntC4IduutGz/uPfpDx5B
    HwJubavlEkflzW/94ft0js3ipotBWuVilnbePNYl8giWv4sqYzW2mb6Q8pepXTgQAS9jtvcq
    OMK+bpFTecF592bI9ggFVcKhUCE=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws;
  s=s1024; d=monstermmorpg.com;
  h=mime-version:from:to:date:subject:content-type:message-id;
  b=Wv5UTcZ+UGA+3lQFrmkQC+9MEZHmzCXde/LwoTgy6TOa7MUf5RnCw1k/5EchsvyF+tT+f5VG
    /cydaefWLntZ58ek1VeSRgQkXO/UYIvqYq6jfG32ag9MOz7SnoMvw7msP/irp42nYWoC+MI3
    vuc0TxMULetZQBOFIA77O0IN+MU=
Received: from MonsterMMORPGServer ([127.0.0.1]) by MonsterMMORPG.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Mon, 11 Jul 2016 17:00:12 +0000
From: "MonsterMMORPG Password Recovery" <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
To: cefurkan@hotmail.com
Reply-To: MonsterMMORPG Administrator <admin@monstermmorpg.com>
Date: 11 Jul 2016 17:00:12 +0000
Subject: MonsterMMORPG Your Game Info
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary=--boundary_182_adaceebe-2ea9-4d4f-a2be-6f04682429c5
Return-Path: noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Message-ID: <MONSTERMMORPGSEHZlJ0005996f@MonsterMMORPG.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Jul 2016 17:00:12.0002 (UTC) FILETIME=[B0028420:01D1DB95]
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: 5a927975-867d-4a4f-b0e1-08d3a9acdec2
X-EOPAttributedMessage: 0
X-EOPTenantAttributedMessage: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa:0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Incoming
CMM-sender-ip: 138.128.2.226
CMM-sending-ip: 138.128.2.226
CMM-Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is
 138.128.2.226) smtp.mailfrom=noreply@monstermmorpg.com; dkim=pass
 header.d=monstermmorpg.com; x-hmca=pass header.id=noreply@monstermmorpg.com
CMM-X-SID-PRA: noreply@monstermmorpg.com
CMM-X-AUTH-Result: PASS
CMM-X-SID-Result: PASS
CMM-X-Message-Status: n:n
CMM-X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0yO1NDTD0w
CMM-X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vQEIc6doRqVYph35rmfBJ4+FB9UePjIVouKKgXAShz+GyxZgf8BFhaKj8+BRm+xXCG3TJ9aBu/Z2GgiRdHFjhJWx9Juz9aWGGd155TSj0gHJe7FiMsXbTSB7FzKyIuk77D+wmCu0KxL95u3rGUynjt7/r/S+/OY21PEOokuREy/vL/Py0eSMPRAnAvjDB9eEsKaV8bllF+0bISEQjAd54zRnMRpc6DJI54=
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
X-Forefront-Antispam-Report: EFV:NLI;SFV:SPM;SFS:(68900001);DIR:INB;SFP:;SCL:5;SRVR:DB4PR08MB0208;H:BAY004-MC5F20.hotmail.com;FPR:;SPF:None;LANG:en;
X-MS-Office365-Filtering-Correlation-Id: 5a927975-867d-4a4f-b0e1-08d3a9acdec2
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB4PR08MB0208;2:l32wZKZDkeUFc4NqZsLGswRaiawDgPGUfCOWb9izVxm5VXXQNb3mQDsYBAs/XFhdpbeYAVQ+wYb5s+5Qvc8xehVOm9GBR4WQy9QOrmXwR+vEkWiPHa1Whf2m7OXzNmb/H6Uj/mnnbB7J27IJCG5qZ07+7D5GQmZ/FXie0vRBoZRSVJXULoNfkedZ0KRz1iCsTNoXh5Y0D53b0nZxzKBd/Q==;3:sSgnjqV1eIsWvZVZK+xAUjENJMrTi18JOBKQLf1+l15Htv0cbtw+z0bvbETcMRWNVArkViioCD1fSDBLKlMJIzw/c9QV6OWcNaE80mmnnpzv+V8LBo8Xr5i5t1uJmTFFw3oRcGyqCBSpOaxv99EhRGIEkH6+ukqXPZ7ELbT+mPM=;25:HrjqSitI1Nn1FR9CciNAhk42ZIYb9cl5UCS4eSVwOWnud6FHU8VAb+PxJwc4dLUxLmsa/YxF2cGEgIsKu/18f5tLef4M1FhoA9tKkga0ejaxhtn2M8gKOoBij2yz09F3qDfBATcStRL7GdUdvunx9yfsvrrPurSrhZTkfqrl3i9yrR24iwFLdx1WJuslpdh7wnLp6KBYYbF41Vys1NJ0PcyGxqWk/zr9ayzc+vlbjkx8Rcj267aj1DndUs3HZFEO4Nz7AlK8JETCQJx7WUHsl9+cMoyqjWLld8g4sfy6TAShIInlgPF2JvVsOkIPfuYWBGOTXufaNCiS2hrtRndMb2obzCmXz5XSKOhxZUkNwOeHp3FT6UK26y9OYVGUXV/RmU3aRhDA+0GIYbWTyqV7z9bvqTEmz2tD+jSwr6DJAlL/nn0fBmLeXHnxXX5Ui2LT
X-Microsoft-Antispam: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(8291501002);SRVR:DB4PR08MB0208;
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB4PR08MB0208;31:rMz4+9ax9/QibLmSYElXNTXZn1E/MQEdgzlG7WtE3yffz17fqRSm4rXB2uQmU1yo8KoyznVLxmTw7Iki+5yEPqgvQeNvobcKH+hfyLZBROI8F2RVt4AiZHLyg1cC2Nt2JDmpYTLsVTRXo3DpFiHOo7u4wS+ZEeZsrwbLmJ9RtJwW75cZTBrHPZyEr2E1hIhmsAwN9rjNZrKqL++7ej1uBQ==;4:X9NQhWiUIOLs8WIy/Qo6lWqsRAIFyz1A3lTtpi3ygwSitp8v7oigEglZf3UCS9OFEivYutE7PhG+gOP23G7wLwrmzB0AD0qNB6K2AGsHc8Z7GbFDMRUdWbnPGllJINzoF1VGVuuL3s+/GiEjCaPOQcKgUEZUaLUyn9dpbnDzgo0rh6E8zG8TowecitW4uYqsAaXrb+Siajm9G1zHdPX89Iavxf8wgqteizJQiewTK6NZoRMzCjk1KmNSkeTkkvskbl8yWfRyiAlmjVgtog7FpA==;23:LZMBDr9dU0JvT5tmFhtcnIwVqlqzD9DcitaYRytxm3EwChXHByAhuRPOY8M/udlr5Pv2ULHgkoDK73kzPXaV49e+HMHWLDTYCh1yLL7xFcCfTw2lgffK6fVgzcYMt9GKwjAz+iYBJ9XY9FXO8llYjk/fT7KhrJND1UI0Kds790cPNW2x4f8CyFbhp1Ojv5qexRlFScjeZhjyJ5rP2QYuK6eZTOlvEY8VRnTkHgAgG40=
X-Exchange-Antispam-Report-CFA-Test: BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:(82015046);SRVR:DB4PR08MB0208;BCL:0;PCL:0;RULEID:;SRVR:DB4PR08MB0208;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 5
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics: 1;DB4PR08MB0208;6:s3jlsUg95+m7Eji6tf7Qq/teHyWPYrJDP7Kcw3PH9ZbvCnLnn5hpOuS75CWhFSJYCRjK4TRegjvqKs4wlsuAacpqDAP0ABa6oeeyzktiOqHT1NgNENVwoH/XW0Ug4dgg28atHFIbtjWVnJE5sYOAUYfdm7QlZadHaGNXA9GERkI+1u15k/m8glHtCWd6yKNEQidb25BbwjYytYZgf3Q0pVFIf8rdtvD+ycG1VkFUdvAgUH3hnWfCuSXUNJ6lkyVu9a7Y1C+LIC7Ktgly1u3FC4cf85BLke86vkdAuqkHXoqaAbE44LCpxneqnoDDrF0H;5:LMpdBxsGfmL5kyGUEFW+410tOd0DaNLLucvTpdJf/5qs+cnZ+iHWY8ERN2eCqPIRX6y4olKPsfDkiWxagyhHViVGwPJ88MwVayCQ69RHULIwEQ/+axhdP5XqGC0oNwe3v/UYeYEx7mLrKhB67Z7+4g==;24:At5AkoCbGkKLyAdrVftAcaGjPQ5h48H/FrRT5m7Temaicfv5Q4wwtmJkxxYvNjr4Ik99P4pj5t3gLN0sRN3rlA==;7:bf1mTXCS7HoBWRAG15xts7mDuirEMPJFIiIZxk8zkHfWG9osIAh6LxOSuE4GbC4vcH7xo7jaiVKIJV1h7XDpAt6HOH0y/yX2FBp1r0vcasaUHaUezcPjQP7K0Nf4VjrTLne4BxcHCPrqLVhWJpQtokv0ov4uxVSLtVHdNBHeMeiigV/NCp7+LBpIfeC7atXdipyvIEwrJAliYoyXGh4lPiq1zM5MTSp4U9mHgfR/iF9g9wRQR9Bn1vzcpCVDgG1/BjyWoP78id2jppNFeX43og==
SpamDiagnosticOutput: 1:22
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-OriginalArrivalTime: 11 Jul 2016 17:00:31.3173
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Id: 84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-FromEntityHeader: Internet
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: DB4PR08MB0208
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: HE1EUR01FT049.eop-EUR01.prod.protection.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-EndToEndLatency: 00:00:02.0914094
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?utf-8?B?MTtBTTNQUjA4TUIwMjAwOzk6a3c2S0d1SVJpN2hKMjVuY2UzV3JWdVNBUkNH?=
 =?utf-8?B?K3RKOUNBbmEvUjBXREx3WE1jVlV0WFhjTklSWXE3dlJWQkZNY1VmbDdmTXZY?=
 =?utf-8?B?UktBM21ma1MzM1JESXVRMWdqLzBiOHZ0NU94bVNqendzbVN4QTRUT2FLWTEw?=
 =?utf-8?B?VXQ3N3o4b094R1JxNG42QTFlcjQ1d0M4cWpzaE5WVVE4VHFJU1NXZVRXZ1Fz?=
 =?utf-8?B?dU1MaFpJT3JTQVoxT1pPZ3pTL28rdnE3dnVRWlJxT3lsREN3c0ZYb1VnSkpt?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZmltcGRCTjhCR1dNMzNTUWlhSGZqN0wrWFBmeGMyWlZtZnBXNDJZL2VwdHp5?=
 =?utf-8?B?R2Jwb05aMUdOWWdVOEZzcU9pemlmb29hWGJVN3RORU1PRTYwU2xJWUZIV1Ni?=
 =?utf-8?B?OFp2WnNYN2ZYUVVnMEdzeHFrWlJtODJtYWJUenQ4a1ZhMkZvMFZaakg1Mkgx?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZUt1M0RyUGNmaTdlUHFOam1Vc2pqVkxySldLd0ZZalZtQ1F1OGt2NUVEM01U?=
 =?utf-8?B?dnJoWE1jVXVvQjlCRXhSZ2JwMGF2Ry81N0p3eFpXaS9QYnQ2NjdFYWhlNUl3?=
 =?utf-8?B?dkpkbW9LVGNIeXpQVGVlOS9TYlVuVTlrUy9yQkR2REJOU1oxWFd3RS9qcGZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?MFJxYnJXVnlHbWt5eDZ3SCtza1BqRUsrOTRRbmorWC9XRDZUam1FTm50VWpE?=
 =?utf-8?B?dHc2bjhTSEd6NTBzLzJBUEl0a1AzcVZ1ZGV4dWtmeGc1TS9QOW5yYm4vRlZF?=
 =?utf-8?B?NkhlLys5REZZaVVURnF0Mjdzb3llelI3WEw5bE1jSmlOenZaRzAwU1lObHB0?=
 =?utf-8?B?RVRiRVNFUjhnNDl5VlRITGZwbFpPTWZhKzdidUdxeFpRODJkSEtIVmhwWENG?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZlFVa280c3VYdis0VndWeXQ5SklicFV5eTVNMlJHWExVNEF5QjllWXlEV0RH?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3VtVFJnSHJpNjZqRnRWVTk2M3hVVGpOWTVBc3pOSkNyUTd6RGMrTVlBOGZl?=
 =?utf-8?B?SXQ5NW1oNFRQN3NIL0t1VUhHcnFpdldxcmxiMzk4KzJKY0w1VS9zNnEwTUZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?dDBMRHllUGVmQ0c5cXFQZy9UOStnWXl4Y2dCdGxCMVMvbmUrWjZKUkVzemo0?=
 =?utf-8?B?K1dyemcvdVJCQ293anBCNm43THNZajJWUnJlcGgrU3l0L3hxQWNvOXhZd3o4?=
 =?utf-8?B?cXU4anRzZjZXYklZZ3h2bExTcGRMeGVWSXpGNGxsczZCZlRzT2hDYWE4T1Bq?=
 =?utf-8?B?S1RUOXdRMU45aFhQWUhoTG9UaEUyY0FxRHA2Q2xPUFJNb2tWV2d1V2tWVnA2?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3ZvQWxzRnN0dz09?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:1;pcwl:1;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:138.128.2.226;WIMS-SPF:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-822:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102409045);OFR:TrustedSenderList;
MIME-Version: 1.0

----boundary_182_adaceebe-2ea9-4d4f-a2be-6f04682429c5
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?utf-8?B?MTtBTTNQUjA4TUIwMjAwOzk6a3c2S0d1SVJpN2hKMjVuY2UzV3JWdVNBUkNH?=
 =?utf-8?B?K3RKOUNBbmEvUjBXREx3WE1jVlV0WFhjTklSWXE3dlJWQkZNY1VmbDdmTXZY?=
 =?utf-8?B?UktBM21ma1MzM1JESXVRMWdqLzBiOHZ0NU94bVNqendzbVN4QTRUT2FLWTEw?=
 =?utf-8?B?VXQ3N3o4b094R1JxNG42QTFlcjQ1d0M4cWpzaE5WVVE4VHFJU1NXZVRXZ1Fz?=
 =?utf-8?B?dU1MaFpJT3JTQVoxT1pPZ3pTL28rdnE3dnVRWlJxT3lsREN3c0ZYb1VnSkpt?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZmltcGRCTjhCR1dNMzNTUWlhSGZqN0wrWFBmeGMyWlZtZnBXNDJZL2VwdHp5?=
 =?utf-8?B?R2Jwb05aMUdOWWdVOEZzcU9pemlmb29hWGJVN3RORU1PRTYwU2xJWUZIV1Ni?=
 =?utf-8?B?OFp2WnNYN2ZYUVVnMEdzeHFrWlJtODJtYWJUenQ4a1ZhMkZvMFZaakg1Mkgx?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZUt1M0RyUGNmaTdlUHFOam1Vc2pqVkxySldLd0ZZalZtQ1F1OGt2NUVEM01U?=
 =?utf-8?B?dnJoWE1jVXVvQjlCRXhSZ2JwMGF2Ry81N0p3eFpXaS9QYnQ2NjdFYWhlNUl3?=
 =?utf-8?B?dkpkbW9LVGNIeXpQVGVlOS9TYlVuVTlrUy9yQkR2REJOU1oxWFd3RS9qcGZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?MFJxYnJXVnlHbWt5eDZ3SCtza1BqRUsrOTRRbmorWC9XRDZUam1FTm50VWpE?=
 =?utf-8?B?dHc2bjhTSEd6NTBzLzJBUEl0a1AzcVZ1ZGV4dWtmeGc1TS9QOW5yYm4vRlZF?=
 =?utf-8?B?NkhlLys5REZZaVVURnF0Mjdzb3llelI3WEw5bE1jSmlOenZaRzAwU1lObHB0?=
 =?utf-8?B?RVRiRVNFUjhnNDl5VlRITGZwbFpPTWZhKzdidUdxeFpRODJkSEtIVmhwWENG?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZlFVa280c3VYdis0VndWeXQ5SklicFV5eTVNMlJHWExVNEF5QjllWXlEV0RH?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3VtVFJnSHJpNjZqRnRWVTk2M3hVVGpOWTVBc3pOSkNyUTd6RGMrTVlBOGZl?=
 =?utf-8?B?SXQ5NW1oNFRQN3NIL0t1VUhHcnFpdldxcmxiMzk4KzJKY0w1VS9zNnEwTUZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?dDBMRHllUGVmQ0c5cXFQZy9UOStnWXl4Y2dCdGxCMVMvbmUrWjZKUkVzemo0?=
 =?utf-8?B?K1dyemcvdVJCQ293anBCNm43THNZajJWUnJlcGgrU3l0L3hxQWNvOXhZd3o4?=
 =?utf-8?B?cXU4anRzZjZXYklZZ3h2bExTcGRMeGVWSXpGNGxsczZCZlRzT2hDYWE4T1Bq?=
 =?utf-8?B?S1RUOXdRMU45aFhQWUhoTG9UaEUyY0FxRHA2Q2xPUFJNb2tWV2d1V2tWVnA2?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3ZvQWxzRnN0dz09?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:1;pcwl:1;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:138.128.2.226;WIMS-SPF:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-822:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102409045);OFR:TrustedSenderList;

Username : denemeemail=0D=0APassword : linkedin.com=0D=0A=0D=0APl=
ease mark this message as not junk/spam
----boundary_182_adaceebe-2ea9-4d4f-a2be-6f04682429c5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Microsoft-Exchange-Diagnostics:
    =?utf-8?B?MTtBTTNQUjA4TUIwMjAwOzk6a3c2S0d1SVJpN2hKMjVuY2UzV3JWdVNBUkNH?=
 =?utf-8?B?K3RKOUNBbmEvUjBXREx3WE1jVlV0WFhjTklSWXE3dlJWQkZNY1VmbDdmTXZY?=
 =?utf-8?B?UktBM21ma1MzM1JESXVRMWdqLzBiOHZ0NU94bVNqendzbVN4QTRUT2FLWTEw?=
 =?utf-8?B?VXQ3N3o4b094R1JxNG42QTFlcjQ1d0M4cWpzaE5WVVE4VHFJU1NXZVRXZ1Fz?=
 =?utf-8?B?dU1MaFpJT3JTQVoxT1pPZ3pTL28rdnE3dnVRWlJxT3lsREN3c0ZYb1VnSkpt?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZmltcGRCTjhCR1dNMzNTUWlhSGZqN0wrWFBmeGMyWlZtZnBXNDJZL2VwdHp5?=
 =?utf-8?B?R2Jwb05aMUdOWWdVOEZzcU9pemlmb29hWGJVN3RORU1PRTYwU2xJWUZIV1Ni?=
 =?utf-8?B?OFp2WnNYN2ZYUVVnMEdzeHFrWlJtODJtYWJUenQ4a1ZhMkZvMFZaakg1Mkgx?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZUt1M0RyUGNmaTdlUHFOam1Vc2pqVkxySldLd0ZZalZtQ1F1OGt2NUVEM01U?=
 =?utf-8?B?dnJoWE1jVXVvQjlCRXhSZ2JwMGF2Ry81N0p3eFpXaS9QYnQ2NjdFYWhlNUl3?=
 =?utf-8?B?dkpkbW9LVGNIeXpQVGVlOS9TYlVuVTlrUy9yQkR2REJOU1oxWFd3RS9qcGZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?MFJxYnJXVnlHbWt5eDZ3SCtza1BqRUsrOTRRbmorWC9XRDZUam1FTm50VWpE?=
 =?utf-8?B?dHc2bjhTSEd6NTBzLzJBUEl0a1AzcVZ1ZGV4dWtmeGc1TS9QOW5yYm4vRlZF?=
 =?utf-8?B?NkhlLys5REZZaVVURnF0Mjdzb3llelI3WEw5bE1jSmlOenZaRzAwU1lObHB0?=
 =?utf-8?B?RVRiRVNFUjhnNDl5VlRITGZwbFpPTWZhKzdidUdxeFpRODJkSEtIVmhwWENG?=
 =?utf-8?B?ZlFVa280c3VYdis0VndWeXQ5SklicFV5eTVNMlJHWExVNEF5QjllWXlEV0RH?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3VtVFJnSHJpNjZqRnRWVTk2M3hVVGpOWTVBc3pOSkNyUTd6RGMrTVlBOGZl?=
 =?utf-8?B?SXQ5NW1oNFRQN3NIL0t1VUhHcnFpdldxcmxiMzk4KzJKY0w1VS9zNnEwTUZy?=
 =?utf-8?B?dDBMRHllUGVmQ0c5cXFQZy9UOStnWXl4Y2dCdGxCMVMvbmUrWjZKUkVzemo0?=
 =?utf-8?B?K1dyemcvdVJCQ293anBCNm43THNZajJWUnJlcGgrU3l0L3hxQWNvOXhZd3o4?=
 =?utf-8?B?cXU4anRzZjZXYklZZ3h2bExTcGRMeGVWSXpGNGxsczZCZlRzT2hDYWE4T1Bq?=
 =?utf-8?B?S1RUOXdRMU45aFhQWUhoTG9UaEUyY0FxRHA2Q2xPUFJNb2tWV2d1V2tWVnA2?=
 =?utf-8?B?d3ZvQWxzRnN0dz09?=
X-Microsoft-Antispam-Mailbox-Delivery:
    abwl:0;wl:1;pcwl:1;rwl:0;ex:0;auth:1;dest:I;WIMS-SenderIP:138.128.2.226;WIMS-SPF:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-DKIM:monstermmorpg%2ec;WIMS-822:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-PRA:noreply%40monstermmorpg%2ecom;WIMS-AUTH:PASS;ENG:(102400050)(102409045);OFR:TrustedSenderList;

<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8">Us=
ername : denemeemail<br>Password : linkedin.com<br><br>Please mark this mes=
sage as not junk/spam=

----boundary_182_adaceebe-2ea9-4d4f-a2be-6f04682429c5--
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to just check the email that you know you are sending, but look for email that you didn't expect to be sending, such as from compromised scripts or email accounts. And yes, verification emails can be marked as spam, too. You could try a double opt-in, where the first email sent is to ask them permission to send other emails, even password recovery emails. Then, have good opt-out information in the email itself.

That being said, your IP seems to be clean on the major blacklists: http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a138.128.2.226&run=toolpage

The bounce is just Microsoft, and they just don't play well with the rest of us. In my experience, I have never found a single incident of spam being sent by any IP that Microsoft has blocked. Their decisions seem to be mostly arbitrary, and typically will include blocking you because you have an IP that looks like an IP that they blocked. So, request a delisting, and don't worry too much about it. If it were up to me, people would stop using such services for their email, but as long as they are, they are probably used to missing email from other legitimate sources also.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two headers PCL between 1-3 is good. But SCL of 5 is considered Spam

```
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: 5
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-PCL: 2
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200686(v=exchg.150).aspx
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205071%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But I also notice the wl:1 (I think they white-listed you), if that's the case you might not have anything to worry about. I think the biggest issue is that you're using GODADDY to send the mail through, I think everyone that uses them has some sort of delivery trouble, because their IP's are commonly abused. You can run your email through a [Email Configuration Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) and see what it turns up.